# cat files with at least 2 specified components in file name

Tags: regex, file, cat

I have file names that looks like this:

```
act-art-atr-phm-pro-psy
act-art-atr-phm-pro-sta
act-art-atr-pro-psy-rel-sta
act-art-atr-pro-tme
act-art-atr-psy
act-art-atr-psy-qud-sta
act-art-atr-psy-sta
act-art-atr-rel
act-art-atr-sta
act-art-com
```

I want to `cat` files that contain at least two specific words (separated by "-") that I manually indicate.

For instance: I want to `cat` all files that contain at least "act" and "psy", thus the resulting file would contain all of the contents from the files

```
act-art-atr-phm-pro-psy
act-art-atr-pro-psy-rel-sta
act-art-atr-psy
act-art-atr-psy-qud-sta
act-art-atr-psy-sta
```

I am not sure of a straight-forward regular expression that would be able to do this, as the order of the file names is unique for each files.

Is there a particular `regex` that can search for files containing at least 2 of the three-lettered names separated by "-" that I can use to `cat` all of the corresponding files?

Or even a more efficient way to handle this task, if my proposed `regex` +`cat` strategy is not the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the filenames contain the terms in alphabetical order. So you could say

```
cat `ls -1 | grep 'act.*psy'`
```

or

```
cat $(ls -1 | grep 'act.*psy')
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I did not think of that but it would truly solve the problem, they are alphabetized!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the file names which are separated by `-` with your words:

```
ls -1 | grep 'word1-word2'
```

If you want to print all the contents of those files:

```
cat $(ls -1 | grep 'word1-word2' )
```